# PHP: 2 Forms, 1 Being File Upload

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have a single profile page that I want to upload a photo on as a separate action. I have the first form submitting to the page successfully, it is when I submit the photo form that the page returns blank with an empty message.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php" id="main">
  <input name="txtFirstName" type="text" value="<?php echo $sFirstName; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="profile.php" id="photo_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <img src="<?php echo($sPath); ?>" height='100' width='100' id="imgProfile" />
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="fUpload" id="fUpload">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="btnUploadPhoto" value="Upload" class="cancel"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if ($_POST['btnSubmit']) {
    $sFirstName = $_POST['txtFirstName'];
  }
  else if ($_POST['btnUploadPhoto']) {
    // DO MY MOVE LOGIC
  }
}
```

When the "btnSubmit" is called the page loads and the textbox gets the name that was entered. When the "btnUploadPhoto" is called I get this on the screen and nothing else:

{error: '', msg: '' }

How do I get the page to reload with the original form?

Comment: blank page = php error, and you've got display_errors/error_reporting turned off. Turn on ALL of the php debugging facilities when trying to track down an error. Otherwise you're trying to chase a black cat through a coal mine at midnight with the lights turned off.

Comment: Marc - I turned on display errors and reporting, I am still getting a page with the {error :'', msg: '' } and nothing else.

Comment: Nothing in your posted code will output the error message you get. There probably is more code you have not posted, that is responsible for what you get. As a workaround, duplicate your profile.php and remove in one file anything related to file upload (should work), in the other anything related to other profile changes, and use two actions in the two forms. This will separate stuff, and you might be able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As you are uploading a file, you will want to check if a file has been submitted in your PHP code. Here is the code to do this:

```
isset($_FILES['fUpload'])
```

Comment: I am getting a valid file and can read the properties of the file. After the post occurs the page has the {error: '', msg: '' } and nothing else loads.

Comment: that is NOT a valid test for an upload. a failed upload will STILL populate $_FILES.